# How to change a text views text more than once?

Tags: android

I tried to change the textview more than once in my activity and then again in my AsyncTask. Is this possible it gave me a error on the line where i changed it the second time.

Comment: seems you have an issue with permissions. Im not an expert on aysnc tasks but that was the issue in the one app I wrote that interacts with an external db on an async clock. I would imagine, though, that you cant do a textView.setText() from an async process... you could push your text value to preferences and have your activity pull from your preferences on Launch. just a thought

Comment: Without showing the code you're using and the error from logcat and the line which causes the problem, it's impossible to provide a definitive answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change it as often as you want.

But keep in mind that an AsyncTask is a seperate thread. If you want to change UI-components, you have to do this in the UI-thread.

This means: If you want to change a UI-control inside the AsyncTask class, you have to do it either inside onPreExecute(), onProgressUpdate() or onPostExecute(). These run in the UI thread and can manipulate Views and layouts. You can't do it inside doInBackground().

Edit: If you want to know more, read the official documentation:
[Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html)

Answer (score 1):

TextView in Android is mutable - it can be written more than once using setText();
Here's the docs. 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView.BufferType)

A more likely problem is that the variable for the TextView is null in the handler function of  the AsyncTask. Check that the textView variable is available to the scope of your asynctask.